# How do I trim out middle initial from a person's full name in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm look for the simplest way to split up first and last name wile trimming out the middle initial.  The current layout of the field is [Last Name], [First Name] [MI].  Also, middle initial is not always there.  My current code is below, I'm just not sure how to trim out the middle initial from first name without writing a case statement.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(h.Name, CHARINDEX(',', h.Name, 0) + 2, LEN(h.Name) - CHARINDEX(',', h.Name, 0)), 0 as FirstName
    ,SUBSTRING(h.Name, 0, CHARINDEX(',', h.Name, 0)) as LastName
FROM Members
```

Comment: I feel it is important to point out: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ regardless of business decisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made some assumptions below:

1 - First names are always longer than one character.
2 - Middle inital will always be preceded by a space.
3 - The data is trimmed.

This code will return `NULL` if any of the above are not true. If your data is not trimmed, you can use `RTRIM` on all instances of `@n` below to mitigate.

```
declare @n as varchar(50)
set @n = 'Smith, John A'
select @n, 
    case 
        when SUBSTRING(@n, LEN(@n) - 1, 1) = ' ' 
        then SUBSTRING(@n, LEN(@n), 1) 
    end
```

Comment: Yup, your assumptions are true and though I was looking for a way around using the case statement this does work and I can't think of any other way to do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What are the business rules of this system? Will it always be:

`last name` <kbd>,</kbd> `first name` <kbd>space</kbd> `a possible middle initial`

What other permutations can exist?

Will it always be <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>letter</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> ? Because then you could always take the right three characters, look for a space and a period, then remove the set of three.

Answer (score -1):

```
select  REPLACE(firstName+ISNULL(middleName+' ','')+ISNULL( lastName +' ',''),'  ',' ') as 'name'  from  Contacts
```